# Not able to match patterns in HTML and JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Guys I coded this in html and js. It is just simple three inputs, NAME, EMAIL and PASSWORD. I validated this simple form in `javascript` but it is not working as expected. I wanted that if I give wrong input to any one of three inputs, it should alert me "Please enter valid credentials." and if I give right input to all of these, It should alert me "Congrats! your form submitted.".

The validation which I gave to NAME field is if length of name is less than 1, it should return false, else true. The validation which I gave to PASSWORD field is same as NAME field and you can see the validation which I gave to all field in my code below. When I give wrong input to only one field, it is still showing me "Congrats! your form submitted."

It is not working as expected!

```js
function ValidateForm(username, email, password)
{
    if ((validateusername(username) || validateemail(email) || validatepassword(password))==false)
    {
        alert("Please Enter Valid Credentials.")
        return false
    }
    else if ((validateusername(username))==true && (validateemail(email))==true && (validatepassword(password))==true)
    {
        alert("Congrats! your form submitted.")
    }
}

function validateemail(email)  
{  
    var x = email.value;  
    var atposition = x.indexOf("@");  
    var dotposition = x.lastIndexOf(".");  
    if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length)
    {  
        return false;  
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}

function validateusername(username)
{
    if (username.length<1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}

function validatepassword(password)
{
    if (password.length<1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

```html
 
    <form name="myForm"> 
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <input type="text" name="EmailAddr" placeholder="Enter Email">
        <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">  
        <button type="submit" onclick="ValidateForm(document.myForm.Name, document.myForm.EmailAddr, document.myForm.Password)">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: Tip: Don't cast booleans to booleans. For example, just `return password.length < 1`. No branching required, or even easier, `return !password.length` as `0` is considered false.

Comment: will it solve problem. Actually i am beginner

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what the problem is here, as it's far from clear. There's a lot of clutter that's making it hard to get to the bottom of it, which is why I mention those things.

Comment: Please can you tell me problem. Take your time if you want.

Comment: That `(...)==false` is also a habit you need to kick. That inverts the meaning of that logic, and it's way to the right, so you have to scroll to see it. Just get rid of the `==true` and `==false` stuff.

Comment: So what should i edit in my code. Plz tell

Comment: I suggest doing the validation strictly on the server side, language does not matter but don't use the front end for anything but submitting the form. This is pretty easy in PHP, and not so easy in node JS if you want it done propely. But even on the front end, the is a lot of work left to do

Comment: Learning SO, and markup: Please edit by changing capitalized "variables" in your description, to the exact spelling of your actual valuables from the code, surrounded by single backtics, like so `password`. As for the error, @tadman above gave you the breakdown. His suggestions should become servings nature to you as a budding programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your if statement condition.

`(validateusername(username) || validateemail(email) || validatepassword(password))==false`

is the same as

`!validateusername(username) && !validateemail(email) && !validatepassword(password)`

so you're saying it should only be considered invalid if all 3 validations fail.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be cleaned up and fixed at the same time:

```js
function ValidateForm(username, email, password)
{
    if (!validateusername(username) || !validateemail(email) || !validatepassword(password)) {
        alert("Please Enter Valid Credentials.")
        return false
    }
    else {
        alert("Congrats! your form submitted.")
    }
}
```

That's all you need. If any one of those fails, then the form fails. Otherwise (`else`) it's fine. You don't need to re-check again.

One improvement you can make is to take as few arguments as necessary without impeding clarity. This function is called "validate form" so I'd expect the form to be the argument, like this:

```js
ValidateForm(document.myForm)
```

Which is easy to accommodate internally:

```js
function ValidateForm(form)
{
    if (!validateusername(form.username) || !validateemail(form.email) || !validatepassword(form.password)) {
        alert("Please Enter Valid Credentials.")
        return false
    }
    else {
        alert("Congrats! your form submitted.")
    }
}
```

Which requires renaming your form fields to be consistent:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
```

> Tip: Try and have one and only one name for your things. Calling it variously `Name` or `name` is really counter-productive.

Comment: The `return` in the if block makes an else block unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Please, never say "not working" here. Give us a **technical description** of the problem. It really helps us understand. Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: @Paul Fair point, but I could refactor this ten times over and I have to stop somewhere.

Comment: @adnan_khan989 I second tadman's comment about not saying "it doesn't work" here. Not only is it not helpful for us, but you'll never learn to code if all you can do is try other people's solutions. You need to understand what's happening for yourself.

Comment: I seem to recall that the validator function needs to return `true` if the form is correct.   The current suggestion would return `undefined` (no explicit return) if the form is correct which is falsy.

Comment: I tried tadman's script but if I do not enter to any of fields it is still showing me "Congrats! your form submitted."

Comment: [This example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm) (basic form validation) explicitly uses `return true;` when the form is correct.

Comment: Tried this too but it is still on same error

Comment: Guys can you please check my code in your editor and discuss after that what is problem.

Comment: I just wanted a solution.

Comment: I didn't get solution I got suggestions

Comment: OK I Understand

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid inlining events.

Take a look.

```js
document.myForm.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);

function validateForm(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   
   const {
   Name: username,
   EmailAddr: email,
   Password: password,
   } = document.myForm;
   
  if (!validateUsername(username) ||
    !validateEmail(email) ||
    !validatePassword(password)) {
    console.log("Please Enter Valid Credentials.")
    return;
  }

  console.log("Congrats! your form submitted.");
}

function validateEmail(emailField) {
  const x = emailField.value;
  const atposition = x.indexOf("@");
  const dotposition = x.lastIndexOf(".");

  if (atposition < 1 ||
    dotposition < atposition + 2 ||
    dotposition + 2 >= x.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return true

}

function validateUsername(username) {
  if (username.length < 1) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validatePassword(password) {
  if (password.length < 1) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name">
  <input type="text" name="EmailAddr" placeholder="Enter Email">
  <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```